# Hide the Docky launcher (from that very dock) in Ubuntu-Xenial-based Linux

Tags: xfce, docky

I want to use the *Docky* dock in Xfce (Mint 18.1).

Is there a way to hide its anchor icon?

[image]

[This](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/remove-anchor-icon-from-docky) old solution doesn't work, as there is no `apps/docky-2/docky/items/DockyItem` in Dconf editor on this system.

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured it out by now, but you can't get to it via dconf-editor. You have to install and use **g**conf-editor.

1. Install gconf-editor via your distro (i.e. `sudo apt-fast gconf-editor`)
2. Run it and navigate to `apps->docky-2->Docky->Items->DockyItem`
3. Uncheck `ShowDockyItem`
4. Restart Docky if the anchor doesn't go away on it's own.

**If all goes well it should end up looking like this:**

[image]

Comment: This works like charm...

Answer (score 0):

You're right. `apps/docky-2/docky/items/DockyItem` is not visible in dconf-editor now. But setting it through command line still works.

```
gconftool-2 --type Boolean --set /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowDockyItem False
```

Get it back with:

```
gconftool-2 --type Boolean --set /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowDockyItem True
```